# Does $x^2 - y^2 = 12345678$ (x,y are integers) have any solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, conic-sections

This question appeared in KVPY online exam held on Nov 5.
This equation is the equation of a hyperbola so any solution must be of the form $a\sec(k),a\tan(k)$. So no solutions.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2505809/prove-that-if-x-is-divisible-by-4-then-x-a2-b2/2505851#2505851

Answer (score 8):

We have $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$ and $12345678=2\cdot3^2\cdot 47\cdot 14593$, so that
$$
(x-y)(x+y)=2\cdot3^2\cdot 47\cdot 14593,
$$
and for any choice of factors, adding $(x-y)$ and $(x+y)$ is odd, so that
$2x=(x-y)+(x+y)$ is odd. So no solutions.

Comment: any graphical way?

Comment: I prefer a modulo argument, which seems more convincing to me than a graphical way.

Answer (score 3):

Since right side is even $x$ and $y$ must be the same parity. So left side is divisible by 4 and right is not. So no solution.

Answer (score 2):

A perfect square is congruent $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$, hence $k+y^2$, where $k\equiv 2\mod 4$ is congruent $2$ or $3$ modulo $4$, hence cannot be a perfect square. Since the given number has the form $4m+2$, there is no solution.